# Slow parsing using python and gzip

Tags: python, gzip

I want to read through a large zipped text file until I reach a line that starts with a certain string, skip ahead to the next place where that string starts the line, and jump back to the original position. I have code that works, but it gets slower and slower as it reaches the end of the file (more that 1 second each). Does anyone know why this is or have a remedy?

This is the basic form:

```
import re
import gzip
fi = gzip.open(...)
s = re.compile(...)
for line in fi:
  if s.match(line):
    start = fi.tell()
    line = fi.readline()
    while not (s.match(line) or line == ""):
      line = fi.readline()
    ...actions...
    end = fi.tell()
    fi.seek(start-end,1)
    fi.readline()
```

**Update:**
Right now the workaround that I am using creates a temporary unzipped file on the disk and reads from there, but this takes time to unzip and copy.

Comment: Just how big is that file?

Comment: How large is your "large zipped text file"? Too large to hold (uncompressed) in memory all at once? I suspect the issue you're encountering is because the `gzip` module's file object doesn't keep the uncompressed file in memory, so seeking requires re-decompressing the whole file up to that point.

Comment: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/gzip.py -- I was double checking source code -- to confirm that it worked this way when you seek -- it rewinds the file then read 1024 byte blocks until it matches the file positions when you seek backwards.

Comment: The file is around 1GB unzipped, so I should be able to unzip the whole file, but I may need to open bigger files in the future.
@GaryWalker, that makes sense, any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: "Right now the workaround that I am using creates a temporary unzipped file on the disk and reads from there, but this takes time to unzip and copy." Many algorithms trade space for speed or speed for space; them's the rules.

Comment: Perhaps you could cache the lines from the start point, and eliminate the need to seek backwards?